# Compare GLM with different dependent variables (that have not the same variance)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, variance, model-comparison

I would like to know if it is possible to compare the effects of one predictor on different response variables that follow e.g. a Poisson distribution. I have already read [this topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8784/comparing-logistic-coefficients-on-models-with-different-dependent-variables) with excellent answers on how to compare coefficients between models. When comparing coefficients, if you have two dependent variables A and B and a predictor C, you can say if  one-unit change of C will lead to a more important change in A or in B. But I have two more questions :

- Suppose we want to know how strong if the relationship between A and C is strong, and if the relationship between A and B is strong. Put differently : we want to know which part of variance of A is explained by C and which part of B variance is explained by C. If the coefficient associated to C is higher in the model A~C than in the model B~C, can we conclude that the effect is "stronger" on A than on B ? I suppose not : e.g. if A has a high variance, its associated coefficient can be high too but that doesn't mean A is strongly explained by C. So my question is : is there a way to compare the amount of variance of A explained by C and the amount of variance of B explained by C ? I'm particularly interested in doing this for GLMs.
- If it is possible, are there widely used methods to do this ? I'm aware of the existence of [Pseudo R-squared](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/Psuedo_RSquareds.htm) for GLM. Would one of this method be appropriate to compare the variances of different variables explained by one predictor ?